# Mailing unique mails (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailing

Tell me which way to think.

I send mailing to several addresses at once. I form a view, which is sent to the addresses. Each email must contain a unique username from a select of all users in the model. Accordingly, each user should have their own view (with their name).

The question is - how to create a unique view for each email in the mailing list?

I cannot write this way, since all users will receive the same email with a list of all usernames:

```
$foreach ($users as $user)
{{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

And how to get result where each user get their name in the letter?

Comment: You need to pass the username in your mail template. Then ypu can assign the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the email for each user individually, passing the user data to the mailable class you have created.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MyCustomUserMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.users.my_custom_user_view');
    }
}
```

In your custom view:

```
{{ $user->name }}
```

Sending the email:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Mail\MyCustomUserMail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        $users->each(function ($user) {
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new MyCustomUserMail($user));
        });
    }
}
```